# How can I combine these queries into one query? or one pl/sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to build a report with jaspersoft studio with oracle pl/sql data source, so I want to combine
these queries to write the procedure.
I'm trying to make a similar report to this one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JkR0.png)

1st query: shows X 1 in the image.

```
SELECT SUM(BD.QUANTITY)   
    FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
   WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
     AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
     AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID IN ( 3,4  ) 
     AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 1  
     AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2   
     AND BM.MONTH = &b3  
     AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
     AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
```

2- shows X 2 in the image.

```
SELECT SUM(BD.QUANTITY)   
    FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
   WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
     AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
     AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID IN ( 3,4  ) 
     AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 2 
     AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2   
     AND BM.MONTH = &b3  
     AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
     AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
```

3- shows Y 1

```
SELECT SUM(BD.QUANTITY)   
  FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
 WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
   AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
   AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 2  
   AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 1  
   AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2  
   AND BM.MONTH = &b3   
   AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
   AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
```

4-  shows Y 2

```
 SELECT SUM(BD.QUANTITY)   
  FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
 WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
   AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
   AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 2  
   AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 2   
   AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2  
   AND BM.MONTH = &b3  
   AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
   AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
```

5-shows Z 1

```
SELECT SUM(BD.QUANTITY)   
  FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
 WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
   AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
   AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 11  
   AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 1  
   AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2    
   AND BM.MONTH = &b3  
   AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
   AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
```

6- shows Z 2

```
SELECT SUM(BD.QUANTITY)   
  FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
 WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
   AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
   AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 11  
   AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 2  
   AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2   
   AND BM.MONTH = &b3   
   AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
   AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
```

7- and this query to get months

```
SELECT SBM.ID MONTH_ID ,SBM.NAME MONTH_NAME FROM SB_MONTH SBM ORDER BY SBM.ID
```

So these quires return first row with &b3 = 1 in the table, and &b3 is a parameter for month
I should fill it from query number 7.
so when &b3 is 1 should return first row, &b3 = 4 should return 4th row.

Any idea how can I combine these quires to achieve that? or any suggestion

my problem is that I don't understand how to combine these quires to create a stored procedure,
and build the report.

Comment: Should &b3 be equal to `SB_MONTH.month_id`?

Comment: Your Oracle version?

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: yes it should &b3 be equal to SB_MONTH.month_id

Comment: Oracle 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate all the needed aggregates separately and then join them to your table with months. Oracle optimizer can push join predicates into the subquery, if needed:

```sql
SELECT 
   SBM.ID MONTH_ID 
  ,SBM.NAME MONTH_NAME
  ,agg.x1
  ,agg.x2
  ,agg.x3
  ,agg.x4
  ,agg.x5
  ,agg.x6
FROM SB_MONTH SBM 
     join (
       SELECT BM.MONTH
             ,SUM(case when BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID IN ( 3,4  ) AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 1 then BD.QUANTITY end) x1
             ,SUM(case when BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID IN ( 3,4  ) AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 2 then BD.QUANTITY end) x2
             ,SUM(case when BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 2         AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 1 then BD.QUANTITY end) x3
             ,SUM(case when BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 2         AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 2 then BD.QUANTITY end) x4
             ,SUM(case when BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 11        AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 1 then BD.QUANTITY end) x5
             ,SUM(case when BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID = 11        AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID = 2 then BD.QUANTITY end) x5
        FROM BRANCHS_MOVE_DTLS BD
            ,BRANCHS_MOVES BM  
       WHERE BD.BRNCHMOVE_ID = BM.ID  
         AND BD.BRNCHMOVE_CURR_ID = BM.CURR_ID  
         AND BD.CLNT_TYPE_ID IN ( 3,4,2,11  )
         AND BD.SUPPLIER_ID IN (1,2)
         AND BD.PTITMMOVTP_ID = 2   
         AND BM.MOVE_TYPE = 2  
         AND BD.PITMMVDLTP_ID = 2
       group by BM.MONTH
     ) agg
     on agg.MONTH = SBM.ID
ORDER BY SBM.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks what do you advice me to read to gain this knowledge?